# How does closed + bounded $\implies$ covering compact?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, compactness

How does a closed and bounded set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ have the property: any open covering reduces to a finite covering? I don't have any intuition for how closed and bounded is linked to reducing infinite to finite, how does this work?

Comment: start by looking at the proof of Heine-Borel theorem

Comment: The Heine-Borel theorem is profound precisely because it isn't obvious. It characterizes what appear to be metric properties in an entirely topological way that abstracts to non-Euclidean spaces.

Comment: The special case where $\Omega$ is the closed interval $[0, 1] \subseteq \Bbb{R} \subseteq \Bbb{C}$ and the covering comprises open disks is a good place to start developing an intuition for the Heine-Borel theorem: clearly for some $x > 0$ , the subinterval $[0, x]$ can be covered by a finite subcover: can the supremum of such $x$ be less than $1$?

Comment: This has little to do with complex analysis. It's much closer to real analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic fact is that $\Bbb R$ is order-complete and this implies that all closed intervals $[a,b]$ are compact (this uses a direct proof using the order topology on $\Bbb R$, you can look it up in Munkres, e.g.). Then we can give a direct proof that a product like $[a,b] \times [c,d]$ also is compact (a direct proof based on the product topology)and finally if $\Omega$ is closed and and bounded in $\Bbb C$ we can find a box $[a,b] \times [c,d]$ that contains $\Omega$ and then $\Omega$ is a closed subspace of a compact set and thus also compact (an easy direct proof). So this specific fact for $\Bbb C$ follows from some general facts plus compactness of closed intervals.